# where is the document for namespace of move_group_interface

Tags: ros, moveit, move-group-interface, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In book, Master ROS for Robotics Programming. I notice this **header file** below

```
//MoveIt! header file
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "test_random_node",
ros::init_options::AnonymousName);
// start a ROS spinning thread
ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
spinner.start();
// this connects to a running instance of the move_group node
// Here the Planning group is "arm"
move_group_interface::MoveGroup group("arm");
// specify that our target will be a random one
group.setRandomTarget();
// plan the motion and then move the group to the sampled target
    group.move();
    ros::waitForShutdown();
}
```

I tried to find the document for this header, but just found  [**planning_interface namespace**](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroup.html) for **move_group.h file** , instead of **move_group_interface namespace**.

**QUESTION1:**

Why?

**QUESTION2:**

Or, maybe actually, it is not a question for ROS but for C++ instead?

**EDIT1**

Document of [MoveGroupInterface](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroupInterface.html), where it shows the header:

```
#include <move_group_interface.h>
```

**QUESTION3:**

If I want to use **MoveGroupInterface class**, how should I write the header **correctly in my own code**?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252157/where-is-the-document-for-namespace-of-move_group_interface/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2017-01-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-17**:
@shawnysh: this is more of a comment and not an answer to this / these question(s), but: could you please not ask multiple questions in a single post? ROS Answers is a Q&A site, not a regular forum. Q&A sites work, because they link question and answer together. If you ask multiple questions in ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-17**:
.. a single post, this system breaks down.

Your previous questions (#q252075) was titled "which node is motion planner in moveit?", but also included questions on moveit action topics and motion planning requests. As the title is what future users see (first), and the title doesn't cover (all) ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-17**:
.. the questions, visibility and searchability suffers.

Please keep this in mind when posting in the future.

Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-17**:
I do like your enthousiasm and inquisitive nature, so keep that up!

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2017-01-17**:
Thanks for your reminder. I just want to demonstrate my questions clearly, cause sometimes several questions pop up together and link to each other, and it seems hard for me to separate them into different posts. I will try hard to take care of it. Thanks for your encouragement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First let's talk about C++ namespaces:

We recently renamed `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup` to `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface` in kinetic, so that's one source of confusion.

And secondly, the `move_group_interface` namespace is obsolete [since hydro](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/indigo-devel/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h#L884), but we only removed it in kinetic.
So the correct way to refer to the class in kinetic is `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface`.

The include question is a good one indeed. The path on the doxygen page is plain wrong.
This is doxygen's default behavior if no explicit include header is specified...

The correct include path can (basically) be seen in the `include` folder of each package.
[In this case](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/tree/kinetic-devel/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/include) it is `#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h>`

-- Edit --

I added a pull-request to change the documentation to the correct include path [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/419).

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2017-01-17**:
Thanks for your reply. It is pleasure to see that my questions can help contribute to the community!

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-01-17**:
It would be even better if you could provide patches yourself. ;)
I know this is hard when you first start with a project, but please consider contributing yourself at some point.
The maintainers (me included) have not that much time to implement such changes... :-)

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2017-01-18**:
I will try it out in the future, now I want to spare more time on the project